# What system should i back up ? system_image or system

Tags: twrp, stock-android

I am trying to backup my system but i have two partitions, `system_image` and `system`.. from inspection i can see that `system_image` is bigger and the format is ext4, While `system` is smaller and the format is emmc ..

I may have the formats (emmc,ext4) in the wrong order.

What do i back up, `system` or  `system_image`  ?

I also have system modifications that I'd like to keep in the backup.

Device :
Android 5.1

Comment: "Android 5.1" is no device but OS and version. To answer the question it might help to know manufacturer and model of the device.

Comment: It makes no difference what device I'm using, only the Android version is required to answer this.

Comment: If you say so. I have multiple devices, some of them were running Android 5.1. None of them had a partition named `system_image`. So if that should be specific to Android 5.1 and not to the device, something must be wrong with all of my devices. But it's your question, so I leave it at that. Good waiting then.

Comment: What method did you use to view the partitions ?

Comment: See my answer on [How to list all major partitions with their labels?](/q/92565/16575). Not one method, but all that are available (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 3):

this concerns TWRP only and is just a different method for backup & restore

have a look in `/etc/recovery.fstab`
you will see the same partition is listed twice

```
/system        ext4  /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system  flags=slotselect
/system_image  emmc  /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system  flags=slotselect
```

first entry is listed as ext4 file system type which tell TWRP the partition is mountable. in case of backup / restore only the content (files) are archived into system.ext4.win (tarball archive)

second entry is listed as emmc which makes TWRP think it is raw disk image. in case of backup / restore the whole partition (including empty space) is cloned bitwise into full partition image system.emmc.win (dd image)

usually /system is sufficient for backup purposes.
/system_image is useful for restoring foreign ROM or backup of corrupt data

Note: for system-as-root devices the mount point is changed into /system_root while /system is just a symlink (or bind mount) of /system_root/system (which is not a representative of whole partition)

Comment: just added because nobody has answered yet

Comment: Awesome write up! Very much appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1591 actually it matters a lot which method for android 10. here some fix for TWRP secontext bug which can be ported to other devices https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-ime-22-06-2020-official-twrp-3-4-0-0-for-htc-u12-aka-imagine.3819343/post-84343017