# App2sd link2sd how to show mount view 2nd micro sd card ext2 partition

Tags: mount, app2sd, link2sd

Question :App2sd link2sd how to show   mount view 2nd  micro sd card ext2  partition

I had loaded  twrp recovery (fastboot boot twrprexovery.img) in bootloader mode and installed SU and rooted and then installed app2sd and link2sd apps.

I had partitioned my 64 gb memory card  30gb fat32  and remaining 32 gb. As ext2  and then  when I tries to view partitions in android 5.1.1 settings>storage it show only one fat 32 partition in sd. Card and not second sd card for ext2

As I want to install 2nd sd card and from recovery or adb pull take NANDROID image backup
Of second partition backup in cloud  and want to see pace and access file system so that I can recover if any thing goes wrong or memory card got corrupted

My queries:-

1. How can I view second partition   of external micro sd card partiton through file manager  or in setting> storage
2. Can I be mounted In boot.init through any aap
3. App2sd  auto created a mount  script to run through recovery to  mount the ext2 partition how to run it in twrp so I have to run through install
4. How to take NANDROID image backup of  system boot recovery internal (userdata partition) and external sdcard 1st and 2nd partitiion and save it in usb drive or cloud storage through adb pull or twrp. Or any other apps how can these files be secured in password or encrypted in cloud
5. As app2sd pro or link2sd plus card link apps and moves lib hex odb files  to which files which are randomly access should be not moved to sd card  and should be left in  internal memory.

**types of files to moved app2sd link2sd**

[image: types of files to moved app2sd]

[image: type of files to be moved link2sd]

[image: app2sd settings linking]

**app2sd eroor mounting script screenshot**

[image: app2sd eroor mounting script screenshot]

[image: eroor app2sd mounting script]

**link2sd error mounting script**

[image: link2sd error mounting script]

Comment: Already explained in my answer to your previous question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526

Comment: @irfan Latif bro questions are different I had asked to  a tool apk to view backup copy external sd card ext2 partition nandroid img file to clous or usb  and viewing it in setting>storage  and that question about parting sd card

Comment: Correct. But I didn't say the question is same. I said what you are asking is already explained there. Spend some time to read and understand things so that you don't have to repeatedly ask similar questions 

Comment: @alecxs Bro I am using link2sd version 4.3.4  patched by  apkmos  tried to install link2sd plus also but it didn't showed  now link2sd is giving error for ceating mount script and app2sd pro when I created partition told me to load install script in boot.init but I didn't notes it  flashed back... The link2sd is not moving or linking apps whereas app2sd is linking app but on every reboot it gave error of  softboot and. Ask to recreate  boot script i will include error photos in question for ur guidence kindly view question as in chat no option to attach photo

Comment: make decision which app you want. uninstall others. read the howto and troubleshooting section. Follow the instructions (have you disabled namespace separation?). If linked apps not available during boot, reason is partition is mounted too late. post location and content of mount script.

Comment: @alecz bro I didnt added mount script manually yet  ..how to fine where is mount script.locatwd any adb shell terminal emulator command or option setiinh in app2sd or link2sd

Comment: @alecxs bro there is no /su/su.s folder as link2sd is not able to create mount script only app2sd crwtes a mount script successfully there is mount-script-recovery.sh in app2sd directory

Comment: @alecx see if this  it works https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/init-d-10-05-2012-super-app2sd-script-major-update-beta.1888986/

Comment: @alecxs bro see this link for app2sd if u ubdestand the solution https://www.reddit.com/r/androidroot/comments/de3n16/fix_required_soft_reboot_on_apps2sd/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=comments_view_all

Answer (score 1):

TWRP is not compatible with Link2SD, therefore one must manually mount MicroSD Card 2nd partition each time before TWRP backup/restore is started.

One can do this from - TWRP menu - Advanced - Terminal

```
mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/sdext2
```

TWRP backup will include 2nd partition in `data.ext4.win` as regular directory `sdext2` therefore it is important to double check `/data/sdext2` is actually mounted before restoring process is started, otherwise TWRP will try to restore all files into phone storage `/data` instead (and probably run out of disk space)

If you prefer to create separate TWRP backup files for 2nd partition (instead of mixed userdata) this can be done from TWRP backup menu.

It requires modified TWRP recovery. Unpack `twrp.img` ramdisk with AIK and add new entry in `/etc/twrp.fstab`

```
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2  ext4  /sd  flags=display="MicroSD 2nd Partition";backup=1
```

This will show you separate entry in TWRP backup menu and create separate `sd.ext4.win` backup files

Comment: @alcex bro thanks a lot for great advice  support knowledge ....bro it may help me  to...take backup of external sd card second partition backup from twrp backup ... If  128gb micro sd card is placed and I create 3 parttion and dictate third ext4 partition  for twrp image backup storage so that when I need revoer I recover from t he third partirin within moments from twrp recovery.... Can we mount 3ed partition and save the twrp backup ext4 images on 3rd partirin to

Comment: TWRP backup can only saved to 1st partition (what's wrong with this?) But you might succeed with external HDD connected via USB-OTG (or cheat TWRP by mounting 3rd partition into */usbotg*)

Comment: bro twrp backup is saved in first partition which is fat32 and it creates a ext4 named file in fat32 ..secondly the reason to theis partition is to permanently store there dedicate for it and recover whenever wherever it crashes...as in pc laptop there is a  button to recover windows hard disk image as when button pressed it recovers from windows shadow or small image restore from a.partition  disk image saved in ..within minutes... So I want that to keep  images in parttion and recover whereaver it goes wrong

Comment: can external HDD be connected through otg as its need voltage from usb ...I have laded usb from otg bit not tries external hdd.... There used to come external hdd casings can it  connect hdd to

Comment: external HDD requires OTG charge hub and external power supply https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYFZA.jpg

Comment: `tar` is the standard unix/linux tool to create backups and can be `gzip` compressed (`.tar.gz` tarball archive) it contains files and permissions. Same for TWRP backup, it uses it's own twrpTar and offers optional (gzip) compression in backup settings. *"when button pressed it recovers"* that's exactly what is TWRP designed for (restore button) there is one directory with date of backup containing all necessary files to restore (except for /sdcard which you can backup manually or by modifying fstab) - TWRP backup is fine, no partition image backup required

Comment: Nevertheless if you insist in partition images instead tarball archives (`.win` files) you can modify fstab and change file system type from `ext4` -> `emmc` to force TWRP creating `dd` partition images (requires more disk space) and you can also add more partitions to TWRP backup menu by simply adding new lines in `fstab` https://android.stackexchange.com/q/194574

Comment: @alcex bro thanks for guidance and help  all link2sd worked successfuly and that to chainfire super user pro  thanks all modified and.mobile.working fine thanks alot beo

Comment: Don't thank me, thank the developer and buy plus version

Comment: bro sorry to trouble you more ...a small problem existing...link2sd linking apps and the remove link option is working great...but problem is some apps (eg Facebook whatsapp) crashes after linking and opening they opens and disaapears and remains opened without displaying .... I tried to remove link ..still fails..Then unistaller the app ..and through sd maid clean corpse or system rremains...then reinstalled them still they are crashing opening anddisappering