# Are system image and system partition the same thing?

Tags: rooting, root-access, bootloader, operating-system

Are system image and system partition the same thing? Are boot image and boot partition the same thing? Been reading about system root and system-less root. On some pages it says you have to modify system partition or boot partition, while on other places it says you have to modify system image or boot image. So is partition and image the same thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What system should i back up ? system\_image or system](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194574/what-system-should-i-back-up-system-image-or-system)

Comment: @alecxs A good answer you have written in the linked question, but I don't think this TWRP specific answer matches this question as it seems to be a more general question.

Comment: An image is a file you have on your PC that contains the data of a partition (or multiple) that can be flashed to an Android device. On the other hand the partition is the data that had already been flashed. Thus the difference is modifying a file on your PC vs. modifying data of an partition directly on your phone. But there may be users who talk about "modifying system partition" while they actually talk about modifying the image file of a system partition.